What is minimal frequency to detect such signal?
I develop simple signal generator, to debug other devices. It sends high logic signal which has length approximately time length 64 microseconds. If i connect some device which has processor frequency, for instance 1MHz, does that device generate interrupt when it gets such signal on the connected pin? What is the lowest frequency, where device can generate interrupts on that signal relaible, even if those signals will be sent periodically?

How would we know? "Some device which has processor frequency" of 1 MHz isn't specific enough to be able to answer.

@JohnD it could be connected to whatever... Arduino, STM and so on. Frequency is matter

@sneiksus we got that, and the answer is: there's no general answer. Sorry. You need to look at the individual, actual devices.

@MarcusMüller, there is really no any formula to calculate minimal frequency needed to catch logical signal?

@sneiksus There's no general formula, the answer depends on the specific device you are connecting to.

The frequency of the CPU is likely not very related to what a specific peripheral (GPIO or maybe some counter capture) can capture.

@EugeneSh. what are important parameters then?

Again, it depends on the very specifics of the device being used and how it is used. For example this STM32 device has some explicit provision for it's external interrupt controller on page 118 in the table ("Pulse width of external signals
detected by the EXTI
controller")

Depending on the device in question, it may even be possible to trigger hardware interrupts on pulses shorter than a clock cycle.

If the device samples the signal once per clock then 1000000/64 Hz is the lowest frequency.  About 16Khz.
But you also need to satisfy set-up times etc.
AVR microcontroller with a 32768Hz crystal would definately be fast enough. 32768Hz is used in clocks, so inexpensive and readily available.
If the device has a latch that can be triggered by the signal then frequency does not matter.  eg: "OHz" halt the device and connect the signal to the wake-up pin.

Finally, normal answer, thanks
